# Error thrown Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: plugins

Help Urgently needed.

My wordpress website has just done some plugin updates and now i cant even log into my wordpress admin/dashboard now and this error message comes up:

Error thrown Call to a member function get() on null

Im not very code savvy which is why im using the easy build wordpress version.

Have I lost control of my website?

Any help urgently needed as it for my self employed business

Comment: The error message comes with a path to the file where this error happens. What does it say?

Comment: All it does is go to a blank white web screen with this exact wording: Error thrown Call to a member function get() on null

Comment: You need to enable `WP_DEBUG` and get the full error code.

Comment: Would you know how and where I can enable wp_debug as I can't even login to the admin site

Comment: If you have access to the file system, you need to edit ```wp-config.php```. In that file change ```define('WP_DEBUG', false);``` to ```define('WP_DEBUG', true);```.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Ive worked out how to get into the files on IONOS site but when looking in the wp-config.php i cant see anything to do with DEBUG.

Comment: scrap that! I could access my files in my IONOS webhosting site but since installing filezilla, i now cant access the files/code

Comment: Thanks all for trying to help with my little experience. I dont know how they did it but my Hosting site IONOS managed to sort it and I can now log in